# Mouse not Working, need to operate Mouse through Keyboard

Tags: hardware, mouse

I have been working on my computer and my Mouse has stopped working. Its optical light is still on, but the cursor is not moving.

But i have no time fix mouse.
I am in real emergency to operate the mouse. In my college times, i have heard of 'Moving and dragging mouse cursor with Keyboard keys'. But i dont know how to do that.

Anyone having knowledge about how to operate mouse cursor with Keyboard keys.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe just unplugging and replugging the mouse helps as well, or a reboot.

Comment: It doesnt work on reboot. is there any shortcuts on keyboard to operate mouse cursor.

Comment: Maybe the mouse itself is broken.  Think you can buy or borrow another mouse?

Comment: I dont that much time to visit market and buy a new one. Need to operate mouse now.

Comment: How do you operate your computer right now then (without the mouse)?

Comment: Found the solution.
press SHIFT+ALT+NUMLOCK.
Click YES on the dialog box to enable sticky keys.
Now i am operating the mouse with numeric keys of the keyboard.

Move combinations for keyboard.
Up-8
Down-2
left-4
right-6
click-5
hold-0
It works.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a Mac answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Mouse Keys under the Mouse & Keyboard section in the Accessibility pane in System Preferences.

This allows you to move the mouse using the keyboard number pad (hold the Option key + number pad key)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

we have had this issue for months - carried out all the tricks mentioned here and at other forums - had some temp luck but the fault always came back-
last night we ran a virus scan and pick up and we removed the virus's - low and be hold the mouse has started working again. 
what we noted was the computer had started to slow down , not much but it was notable, the odd wierd thing would happen now and again ,then the mouse stopped working , - any way all is good now after the scan and dumping them into the trash